# Error checking in java while converting a string to a double

Tags: java, jsp, exception, error-handling

I an tryin to convert a string array to a double array, depending on what weather station was chosen from database - some weather stations have no data, so the whole string array is filled with nulls(12 of them in fact) So obviosly if one of them stations is chosen I get an exception. I realy have no time to write a lot of code to work around it, since I have to submit my work very soon... Is there any solution to catch it and display an error message to user insted of lines and lines explaining an error? Thanks!

Here is the loop to convert a string array into a double array

```
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
{   
avMaxTempOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(avMaxTempSplit[i]);
avMinTempOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(avMinTempSplit[i]);
meanTempOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(meanTempSplit[i]);
highestTempOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(highestTempSplit[i]);
lowestTempOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(lowestTempSplit[i]);
maxWindOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(maxWindSplit[i]);
totalRainfallOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(totalRainfallSplit[i]);
maxDayRainfallOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(maxDayRainfallSplit[i]);
rainDaysOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(rainDaysSplit[i]);
totalSunshineOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(totalSunshineSplit[i]);
mostSunshineDayOptimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(mostSunshineDaySplit[i]);

avMaxTemp2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(avMaxTemp2Split[i]);
avMinTemp2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(avMinTemp2Split[i]);
meanTemp2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(meanTemp2Split[i]);
highestTemp2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(highestTemp2Split[i]);
lowestTemp2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(lowestTemp2Split[i]);
maxWind2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(maxWind2Split[i]);
totalRainfall2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(totalRainfall2Split[i]);
maxDayRainfall2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(maxDayRainfall2Split[i]);
rainDays2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(rainDays2Split[i]);
totalSunshine2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(totalSunshine2Split[i]);
mostSunshineDay2Optimised[i] = Double.parseDouble(mostSunshineDay2Split[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do you wanna do, when you encounter a null, do you wanna print an error? or do you wanna save a 0 ? a -1 ?

Comment: Yes I want to print en error, I think it not even 0 - if it was I would not get an error, it is NULL

Comment: And a NULL cannot be converted to a double

Comment: My eyes are burning !

Comment: So then you could wrap your for in a try catch block, and print the message in the catch.

Comment: Thanks, I was actully trying that - but made a little mistake there

Answer (score 0):

if you do try/catch outside for loop, you'll stop processing the rest of the loop.  Try/catch inside for loop is probably closer, as long as you don't mind the unassigned values left in the array.  Something like this might be best, changing Optimized arrays to type Double[]:

```
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
{   
avMaxTempOptimised[i] = safeDouble(avMaxTempSplit[i]);
avMinTempOptimised[i] = safeDouble(avMinTempSplit[i]);
meanTempOptimised[i] = safeDouble(meanTempSplit[i]);
highestTempOptimised[i] = safeDouble(highestTempSplit[i]);
lowestTempOptimised[i] = safeDouble(lowestTempSplit[i]);
maxWindOptimised[i] = safeDouble(maxWindSplit[i]);
totalRainfallOptimised[i] = safeDouble(totalRainfallSplit[i]);
maxDayRainfallOptimised[i] = safeDouble(maxDayRainfallSplit[i]);
rainDaysOptimised[i] = safeDouble(rainDaysSplit[i]);
totalSunshineOptimised[i] = safeDouble(totalSunshineSplit[i]);
mostSunshineDayOptimised[i] = safeDouble(mostSunshineDaySplit[i]);

avMaxTemp2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(avMaxTemp2Split[i]);
avMinTemp2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(avMinTemp2Split[i]);
meanTemp2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(meanTemp2Split[i]);
highestTemp2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(highestTemp2Split[i]);
lowestTemp2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(lowestTemp2Split[i]);
maxWind2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(maxWind2Split[i]);
totalRainfall2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(totalRainfall2Split[i]);
maxDayRainfall2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(maxDayRainfall2Split[i]);
rainDays2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(rainDays2Split[i]);
totalSunshine2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(totalSunshine2Split[i]);
mostSunshineDay2Optimised[i] = safeDouble(mostSunshineDay2Split[i]);
}


...

safeDouble( String str){
return str== null ? null : Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Add in quick null checks where you read Optimized arrays and you're golden.